# Properties are Nil when calling functions from a selector in another class

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, selector

I have a subclass of `UIView`, in this custom view, I add a gesture recognizer during initialization.

```
let gameBoard = GameBoardViewController()
```

and

```
func initGestureRecognizers() {

    let panRec = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: gameBoard, action: #selector(GameBoardViewController.labelDragged(_:)))
    self.addGestureRecognizer(panRec)
    self.clipsToBounds = true
    self.userInteractionEnabled = true
}
```

In the `viewDidLoad` of `gameBoardViewController`, I initialize `randomNumber = 10` .

The problem i'm having is that in the `labelDragged` function (which I call from the selector in my `UIView` subclass when it is dragged ), `randomNumber` is Nil.

I don't have this problem when I add the gestureRecognizer from `gameBoardViewController`.

Can anyone tell me what i've done wrong? Thanks

Comment: How does your labelDragged function look? Does it take a GestureRecognizer. Like labelDragged(sender:UIGestureRecognizer) ? 

Also try initializing the GestureRecognizer later when the view is fully loaded. in viewDidLoad or lazy loading it in viewWillApperar.

Comment: yes, labelDragged takes a gestureRecognizer, `func labelDragged(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) `. My custom `UIView` subclass is also created during `viewDidLoad` of `gameBoardViewController`

Comment: But do you add your GestureRecognizer in the viewDidLoad or the init method? 
I have experienced same problem, and as i remember self.addGestureRecognizer only works in initWithFrame, otherwise you can have en commonInit method that you call from all your initializers or simply add the GestureRecognizer in viewDidLoad

Comment: My GestureRecognizer is in my `UIView` subclass, I initialize and add it in `override init(frame : CGRect)` . My `UIVew` subclass is initialized in the viewDidLoad of `gameBoardViewController` (my main view controller)